# How to properly apply index_desc hint for a remote database object in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle12c, dblink

We were facing some issues with execution plans while accessing remote database objects with dblink. Here is the query itself run on the remote database:

```
select --+  index_desc (d DAY_OPERATIONAL_PK) 
 d.oper_day
  from day_operational d
 where rownum = 1
```

The plan for this query is the following :

```
 Plan Hash Value  : 2761870770 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name               | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                    |    1 |     8 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 |   COUNT STOPKEY               |                    |      |       |      |          |
|   2 |    INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING | DAY_OPERATIONAL_PK |    1 |     8 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This one works correct that is it returns the last operational day. In this case 14.09.2021. However if execute this exact same query from other database connecting to this one via dblink, wrong results are returned . In this case the first row of the table is returned - 05.09.2009.
Here is the query:

```
select --+  index_desc (d DAY_OPERATIONAL_PK) 
 d.oper_day
  from day_operational@iabs d
 where rownum = 1
```

The plan generated for this query in local database is the following:

```
 Plan Hash Value  : 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name               | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT REMOTE |                    |    1 |     8 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 |   COUNT STOPKEY         |                    |      |       |      |          |
|   2 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | XPKDAY_OPERATIONAL |    1 |     8 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As it can be seen, the plan generated when connected via dblink uses full table scan and ignores index_desc hint. How could we enforce oracle to use this index? Tried adding driving_site hint but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for confusions. It occured that index names in local database and remote database are not same and therefore hint was ignoring since there was no index with that name in the remote db. With right index names, both the plan and result were correct